# Excute script for n minutes in a user defined range of time

Tags: php, python, mysql, server, cron

I want to execute a php or python script on a server with values from a database for n minutes a day in a user defined range of time which I would like to store in a database too. So my question is: How can I achive this the most performant and scalable way?

So a user should set a range of time in which the script should be executed, I couldn't figure out how i could do this if multiple users selected the same range of time.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`cron`](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) and [`gearman`](http://gearman.org/).

Both are services that run on linux and would be able to execute either PHP or Python scripts in a predictable and scalable way.

The basic structure of your mechanism would be...

1. **Job initiator** - this script would be invoked automatically by cron (every minute max). It would execute very quickly and then exit. You would use this to check the DB for jobs that should be started during that minute, and pass them off to Gearman.
2. **Job executor** - this script executes a single job. Since Gearman handles concurrency for you, you only have to worry about doing a single long-running process here.

You can easily configure Gearman to handle many concurrent jobs. Also, there are good Gearman packages for both [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gearman/) and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) (I've used them both with great success).

Here is some pseudocode to help you understand how this would work:

**initiate.php**

```
<?php

$gearmanClient= new GearmanClient();
$gearmanClient->addServer();

$workloads = fetchWorkloads(time());

foreach ($workloads as $workload) {
  $gearmanClient->doBackground('execute', json_encode($workload));
}
```

**execute.php**

```
<?php

$gearmanWorker = new GearmanWorker();
$gearmanWorker->addServer();
$gearmanWorker->addFunction('execute', 'executeMethod');

while($gearmanWorker->work()) {
  // Handle any errors here
}

function executeMethod($job) 
{
  $workload = json_decode($job->workload());

  while (time() < $workload->stopTime) {
    // Do your task for an amount of time here
  }
}
```

Again, this is just pseudocode. You will need to flesh it out based on your requirements. Obviously you'll also need to learn, install, and/or configure cron and Gearman.

Your cron entry might look like this:

```
* * * * * www-data php /var/www/my-app/initiate.php
```

For Gearman, I would recommend using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to ensure that your workers are restarted, etc when they inevitably encounter problems. Your supervisor config might look like this:

```
[program:myProgram]
user=www-data
command=php /var/www/my-app/initiate.php
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=KILL
```